# Galaxy S4 dropped screen is black

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, broken-screen

Situation is this: I took my phone out of my pocket and dropped it from about pocket height on a sort of tiled floor. The screen then became green and had lines. Then the screen just turned off. When I looked for physical damage, all I can see are tiny cracks at the top right of the screen. Everything else works fine (home button, back button, vibration, led, etc.) How would I fix this or do I need to go to a repair shop. Thanks in advance.

Also I have the T-mobile version. I don't know if that matters.

Comment: Look for similar posts by users with issues caused by broken screen under `brokenscreen` [tag](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/broken-screen)

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem you will need to either purchase and follow instructions on installing a new screen or take your phone to a local repair shop.